# Referring to resources named with variables in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create a module in Terraform that can be instantiated multiple times with different variable inputs. Within the module, how do I reference resources when their names depend on an input variable? I'm trying to do it via the bracket syntax (`"${aws_ecs_task_definition[var.name].arn}"`) but I just guessed at that.

(Caveat: I might be going about this in completely the wrong way)

Here's my module's (simplified) `main.tf` file:

```
variable "name" {}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "${var.name}" {
    name = "${var.name}_service"
    cluster = ""
    task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition[var.name].arn}"
    desired_count = 1
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "${var.name}" {
    family = "ecs-family-${var.name}"
    container_definitions = "${template_file[var.name].rendered}"
}

resource "template_file" "${var.name}_task" {
    template = "${file("task-definition.json")}"

    vars {
        name = "${var.name}"
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error loading Terraform: Error downloading modules: module foo: Error loading .terraform/modules/af13a92c4edda294822b341862422ba5/main.tf: Error reading config for aws_ecs_service[${var.name}]: parse error: syntax error
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I was fundamentally misunderstanding how modules worked.

Terraform does not support interpolation in resource names (see the [relevant](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/571) [issues](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1976)), but that doesn't matter in my case, because the resources of each instance of a module are in the instance's namespace. I was worried about resource names colliding, but the module system already handles that.

Comment: Also, apparently you can't interpolate resource names. (Yet?)

Comment: As this stands this is not a useful answer for anyone else with a similar issue. I'd suggest you either rework the answer to explain why the error was happening and how to fix it (particularly focusing on the fact that you can't interpolate resource names) or delete the question/answer combo.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, good call. I've updated my answer to clarify, but I'm also fine with deleting this question/answer combo if it's not useful to anyone else.

Comment: i found this useful. and especially thanks for pointing to the relevant resources

Comment: This question and answer helped me too. I'm trying to do the same thing and realizing it can't be done.

Answer (score 8):

The picture below shows what is going on.

The terraform documentation does not make their use of **"NAME"** clear versus the **"name"** values that are used for the actual resources created by the infrastructure vender (like, AWS or Google Cloud).

Additionally, it isn't always **"name=**, but sometimes, say, **"endpoint=** or even **"resource_group_name=** or whatever.

And there are a couple of ways to generate multiple **"name"** values -- using count, variables, etc., or inside tfvar files and running **terraform apply -var-file=foo.tfvars**

[image: terraform resource]