# Terraform config file : Using variable inside a variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am tring to create a terraform configuration file to create an ec2 instance. I am using the `variables.tf` file to put all my variables. It works for most of the cases but there are two cases which I am not able to achieve. Any pointers is much appreciated.

1.using variable for aws instance name. Using `var.service_name` or `"${service_name}"` does not work.

```
    resource "aws_instance" var.service_name {
       ami           = "ami-010fae13a16763bb4"
       instance_type = "t2.micro"
        .....
    }
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619691/referring-to-resources-named-with-variables-in-terraform) explains that resource name cannot be variables. But this is pretty old. Not sure if this is still the case.

2.Using variable inside another variable. For example I have connection parameters defined like this

```
connection {
           host = "${aws_instance.terraformtest.public_ip}"
           type     = "ssh"
           user     = "ec2-user"
           private_key = "${file("C:/Users/phani/Downloads/microservices.pem")}"
}
```

This works. I am using the ip generated from aws instance resource. But If i use it like this. It doesn't work

```
host = "${aws_instance.${service_name}.public_ip}"
```

Am I missing something or is there a workaround

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Referring to resources named with variables in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619691/referring-to-resources-named-with-variables-in-terraform)

Comment: just for handy read terraform resource doesn't supports variable substitution in resource name

Comment: How about variables inside variables?

Answer (score 0):

Resource names in Terraform are required to be constants. In practice this usually isn't a problem, because a resource name only needs to be unique within a given module and so it shouldn't ever be necessary for a caller to customize what a resource is named in a child module. In the case where a particular resource is the primary object declared by a module, a common idiom is to name the resource "main", like `resource "aws_instance" "main"`.

In situations where you need to declare several instances whose definitions share a common configuration, you can use [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) or [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count) to produce multiple instances from a same resource block. In that case, the resource addresses include an additional "index" component, like `aws_instance.example["foo"]` or `aws_instance.example[0]`, where the *index* can be a variable to dynamically select one of the instances produced by a single resource block.